# MySQL select multiple row on table 2 with two differents Id from table 1 result in one row as two differents fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible in only one MySQL query to get the desired result (below) returned into one row ?

Where id=1 in Table 1

Table 1

```
|------|----------|----------|
| id   | refIdOne | refIdTwo |
|------|----------|-----------
| 1    | 1        | 2        |
|------|----------|-----------
```

Columns "refIdOne" & "refIdTwo" refer Table 2 "id" column

Table 2

```
|------|------------------|
| id   | text             |
|------|------------------|
| 1    | cheese           |
| 2    | made with milk   |
|------|------------------|
```

Desired result returned in ONE ROW with custom AS columns named "subject" and "description" :

```
|----------|-----------------|
| subject  | description     |
|----------|-----------------|
| cheese   | made with milk  |
```

? Many thanks for help

*** EDIT : Answer is ***

```
select t21.text as subject, t22.text as description
from Table1 as t1
join Table2 as t21 on t1.refidone = t21.id
join Table2 as t22 on t1.refidtwo = t22.id
where t1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table2 has to joined twice to Table1.

```
select t21.text as subject, t22.text as description
from table1 t1
join table2 t21 on t1.refidone = t21.id
join table2 t22 on t1.refidtwo = t22.id
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is working but how can I limit the result where Table1.Id = 1 ?

Comment: add it as a `where` clause.

Comment: where adding `where` ? I try different solution `WHERE Table1.Id=1` but got invalid syntax in query.

Comment: this is not a spoon-feeding forum. you should put in some effort. learn basic sql syntax first.

Comment: you are right it was simple, there was just an error in my table
I added the full answer into the main post

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform `Self join`. Join `Table2`.`ID` twice with `Table1`.`refIdOne` and `Table1`.`refIdTwo`

```
select t2.text as subject, t3.text as description 
from Table1  t1 
Left join Table2 t2 on t1.refIdOne = t2.id
Left join Table2 t3 on t1.refIdTwo = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

without joins

```
SELECT
(SELECT text FROM Table2 WHERE id = (SELECT refIdOne FROM Table1 WHERE id = 1) ) AS name,
(SELECT text FROM Table2 WHERE id = (SELECT refIdTwo FROM Table1 WHERE id = 1) ) AS description
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. It seems this one is near what I'm looking for but it seems there is a syntax error. Any idea?

Comment: Before appling compare speed with joins syntax